# kotlin - how to minimise the if statement with null checks

Tags: kotlin

I doing a small calculation and I have a if clause where I am checking if any of the value is null then donot perform the operations

Is there an easy way to write this in Kotlin without so many null checks  in a if statement

```
   if (pfTotal != null && departureTotal != null && upTotal != null && density != null) {
                    customArDisc =
                        (pflTotal - (departureTotal - upTotal)) / density * THOUSAND
                    customArDiscPercentage =
                        customArDisc / (pfTotal / density * THOUSAND) * PERCENTAGE
                }
```

Thanks in advance
R

Comment: Design the object so none of those values can be null.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a lot shorter (not for four things anyway), but you could do something like

```
val dependencies = listOf(pfTotal, departureTotal, upTotal, density)
if (dependencies.all { it != null }) {
    // do stuff
}
```

or for nulls specifically

```
if (!dependencies.contains(null))
```

and you could write a nicely named extension function/property that's clearer about what you're doing and what it's used for.

Bear in mind, if those are `var`s and not `val`s then there's no guarantee they're still non-null once you try to use them!

---

Another approach you could use is some kind of state object/data class that holds non-null versions of each property. And to create it, you call a builder function with all those values, it does the null checking, and returns the complete object, or `null` if one of the values was null.

That way, you either have the valid state object to do your calculations with, or you don't. This is just pushing the null check into a different place, but it might be helpful if you're doing a bunch of things with one set of data, and you just want to validate it once

---

Or you could just YOLO it and wrap your function in a try/catch that looks for `NullPointerException`s. Wouldn't recommend it though!

Comment: `!dependencies.contains(null)` could be simplified to `null !in dependencies`.  (But I wouldn't recommend that approach, for performance reasons.)

Comment: @gidds I always forget about ``in``, I don't know why!

Comment: Smart-casting won't be available inside `if` block with this approach

Comment: @МихаилНафталь true, and you'd have to whip out our old friend ``!!``. Hey I never said any of this was a good idea... (it would be a legit use of ``!!`` for once though)